# saving file in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap

I previously used the shared object to save my game's progress data...

so i made a big array and saved the values of the variables and saved it into a cookie..

but this time I am using some bitmap screenshots..so the same method doesn't seem to work if I make a variable that gets a value after those bitmaps have been made and save into a cookie..when I load it the bitmaps disappear..

does anybody know a way I can save these bitmaps with the cookie? or any other file saving method??

### *EDIT

```
var bmp:BitmapData;
var myImages:Array = new Array();

red_square.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, firstchoice);
    function firstchoice (e:MouseEvent){

        bmp = new BitmapData(167, 167);
       myImages[0] = new Bitmap (bmp);
        addChild(myImages[0]);
        myImages[0].x=151;
        myImages[0].y=371;
        bmp.draw (red_square);
            gotoAndStop(5);

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the Bitmap data in a cookie, you can pass it to a byteArray and then pass it to  a Base64 String. You can save it inside a cookie. To use it you can just do the reverse procedure.

But I don't think that save screenshots in cookies is a good policy. As you are using actionScript 3, I would save everything using [Flash Shared Objects](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/).

You can pass it to a PNG or JPG bytearray using the [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) classes:

```
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder( 85 );
var bytes:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode( btm );
```

or

```
var bytes:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode( btm );
```

and them save the bytes into LocalStorage

```
var screenshots:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("screenshotsObjectID");
if (screenshots.data == null){
    screenshots.data = {};
}
if (screenshots.data.screensObject == null){
    screenshots.data.screensObject = {};
}

screenshots.data.screensObject["someStringToIdentifyTheImage"] = bytes;

screenshots.flush();
```

You can save the images as you want. You can change someStringToIdentifyTheImage to be a sequence number, a timestamp or any other thing. Or you can just say that screensObject is a«n Array and just push the images inside it.

Comment: oh so can u give me an example about how would I turn it into a byte array and save that array? please

Comment: Can you put here an example of the code where you have the bitmap data?